# How to pass value of a textbox from one form to another form in access

Tags: ms-access

I have create two forms, named Main and Individual. Main has one table named `frmFID`, and a combobox named `frmEth`. I want to send the `frmID` value to another textbox which is present in another form.

```
Private Sub cmdLog_Click()
Dim abc As String
Dim xyz As String
abc = "Insert into Main(FID, Ethnicity) Values('" & Me.frmFID & "', '" & Me.frmEth & "')"
CurrentDb.Execute (abc)

xyz="Insert into Individual(FID) Values(' "& Me.frmFID & "')"
CurrentDb.Execute(xyz)

DoCmd.Close
DoCmd.OpenForm "Individual"
End Sub
```

Comment: please format your code

Answer (score 0):

Your code is pretty much unreadable the way it is formatted. In any case you can send data to a form that you are opening by using the `OpenArgs` parameter of `DoCmd.OpenForm`. If the form is already open you can access it from anywhere like this:

```
Forms([FormName]).[TextBoxName]="Value to Push"
```